# SSMS Creating view with specific column properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, create-view

I am trying to create a view, but I would like a column to be (CHAR(15), not null) - here is the SQL:

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[High_Radius_AR_Extract] as
SELECT  T1.CUSTNMBR as [Customer Number] <- this is the column I would like to be a CHAR 15
```

I can't seem to get the syntax correct, any help would be appreciated.

CCC

Comment: What's the data type in the underlying table, and why does data type matter in a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it in the desired format:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[High_Radius_AR_Extract] as
SELECT  CAST(T1.CUSTNMBR as Char(15)) as [Customer Number]
```

Hope this helps.